# What's Kotlin equivalent of Class<?>

Tags: kotlin

I want a map between `Int` and any class. In Java it would be `Map<Class<?>, Integer>`. What's the Kotlin equivalent of that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) is Kotlin's equivalent to `java.lang.Class`.

An instance of `KClass` can be obtained with `::class` on either a type or a value (i.e. `String::class`, `3.8::class`).

If you require a Java `Class` instance from a `KClass` you can use the [`java` extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html):

```
val kotlinClass: KClass<String> = String::class
val javaClass: Class<String> = String::class.java
```

Keep in mind that if you want to use kotlin-reflect's [full features](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#reflection) you will need [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) on the classpath.

So in your case, the equivalent would be `Map<KClass<*>, Int>`.

Answer (score 10):

The equivalent declaration would be  `Map<Class<*>, Int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for KClass. You need to add the Kotlin reflection library in order to use it.